# How can I update progress bar value in WPF MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, progress-bar

My question is how go show progress on progressbar if I have to call my method only once? I am working on MVVM project in WPF. I have to display progress of my loop on the progressBar. If i have got something like this in Model class, my ProgressBar is updating correctly, but only once

```
        public double progressBarValue;
        public string inputText;
        public int quantityOfNumbers
        {
            get;
            set;
        }


        public void inputTextToInt(string inputText)
        {
            progressBarValue = Convert.ToInt32(inputText);
            quantityOfNumbers = Convert.ToInt32(inputText);
            
            //work();
        }
```

[image]

But if I've tried to updating in real time my progressbar, with these code:

```
        public void inputTextToInt(string inputText)
        {
            //progressBarValue = Convert.ToInt32(inputText);
            quantityOfNumbers = Convert.ToInt32(inputText);
            
            work();
        }

        private async void work()
        {
            RandNumbers randNumbers = new RandNumbers(quantityOfNumbers);
            var progress = new Progress<double>(value =>
            {
                progressBarValue = value;
                Console.WriteLine(progressBarValue);
            });

            await Task.Run(() => randNumbers.RandAllNumbers(progress));
        }
```

There isn't any progress on my ProgressBar. I've checked on console and in this line my progressBarValue is changing correctly But it isn't sending to my ViewModel class.

```
progressBarValue = value;
```

And this is my ViewModel class:

```
private ModelTME_App model = new ModelTME_App();

        public string inputText
        {
            get { return model.inputText; }
            set { model.inputText = value; 
                onPropertyChanged(nameof(inputText));
            }
        }

        public double progressBarValue
        {
            get {
                Console.WriteLine(model.progressBarValue);
                return model.progressBarValue;
            }
        }

        private ICommand inputTextToInt = null;

        public ICommand InputTextToInt
        {
            get
            {
                if(inputTextToInt == null)
                {
                    inputTextToInt = new RelayCommand(
                        (object o) =>
                        {
                            model.inputTextToInt(inputText);
                            onPropertyChanged(nameof(progressBarValue));
                        },
                        (object o) =>
                        {
                            return model.progressBarValue == 0;
                        });
                }
                return inputTextToInt;
            }
        }


        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        private void onPropertyChanged(string nameOfProperty)
        {
            if(PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameOfProperty));
            }
        }
    }
```

My RelayCommandClass

```
public class RelayCommand : ICommand
{
    private Action<object> execute;
    private Func<object, bool> canExecute;

    public RelayCommand(Action<object> execute, Func<object, bool> canExecute = null)
    {
        if (execute == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(execute));
        }
        else
        {
            this.execute = execute;
        }
        this.canExecute = canExecute;
    }

    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged
    {
        add
        {
            CommandManager.RequerySuggested += value;
        }
        remove
        {
            CommandManager.RequerySuggested -= value;
        }
    }

    public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        if(canExecute == null)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return canExecute(parameter);
        }
    }

    public void Execute(object parameter)
    {
        execute(parameter);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `Binding.Source` must always raise the `INotifyPropertyChanged.PropertyChanged` event to trigger the `Binding` to update update the `Binding.Target`.

You should avoid binding to the *Model* via a delegating property. The Model shouldn't expose an API to allow this (data hiding).
The proper pattern would be to implement a `ProgressChanged` event in the *Model* that the *View Model* can observe.

Also avoid a few code smells:

- Never return `void` from an `async` method except the method is an event handler. An `async` method must return `Task` or `Task<T>`. The returned `Task` must be propagated and awaited up the call chain.
- Avoid capturing member variable in lambdas. This can create a memory leak in certain situations
- Pass values from *View Model* to *Model* using methods. Exposing all *Model* properties to the *View Model* exposes too much information details (like which properties to set to change the *Model* to a valid state). Instead make public method request the required data as parameters or parameter objects. The properties should be private (except those required to configure the object).
- Using member and parameter names like `ProgressBar...` or `InputText...` gives a hint that your model is not properly designed. Since the model is unaware of the view, it is not interested in progress bars or input text too. Could be a simple naming issue or a serious design issue.
- You should try to implement the official C# [Naming Guidelines](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/naming-guidelines#in-this-section)

**Model.cs**
The `ProgressChanged` event is defined using the [`ProgressChangedEventArgs`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.progresschangedeventargs?view=net-6.0).

```cs
class Model
{
  public event EventHandler<ProgressChangedEventArgs> ProgressChanged;
  private double ProgressPercentage { get; set; }
  private string NumericText { get; set; }
  private int QuantityOfNumbers { get; set; }

  protected virtual void OnProgressCHanged(double percentage)
    => this.ProgressChanged?.Invoke(new ProgressChangedEventArgs(percentage, string.Empty);

  public async Task<int> ToIntAsync(string numericText)
  {
    NumericText = numericText;
    QuantityOfNumbers = Convert.ToInt32(NumericText);
    await WorkAsync();
    
    return QuantityOfNumbers;
  }

  private async Task WorkAsync()
  {
    // Can you guarantee that this method is called from the UI thread?
    var progress = new Progress<double>(value =>
    {
      ProgressPercentage = value;
      Console.WriteLine(ProgressBarValue);
      OnProgressChanged(ProgressBarValue);
    });

    // Avoid capturing member variables in lambdas
    int quantityOfNumbers = QuantityOfNumbers;

    await Task.Run(() => 
    {
      var randNumbers = new RandNumbers(quantityOfNumbers);
      randNumbers.RandAllNumbers(progress));
    });
  }
}
```

**ViewModel.cs**

```cs
class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
  private Model _model;

  // TODO::Let property raise PropertyChanged event
  public double ProgressValue { get; set; }

  public ICommand InputTextToIntCommand => new RelayCommand(ExecuteInputTextToIntCommandAsync);

  // TODO::Let property raise PropertyChanged event
  public string NumericText { get; set;}

  public ViewModel()
  {
    _model = new Model();
  }
    
  // Make sure RelayCommand can execute async delegates
  private async Task ExecuteInputTextToIntCommandAsync()
  {    
    _model.PropgressChnaged += OnProgressChanged;

    // Pass value to model
    var quantityOfNumbersResult = await _model.ToIntAsync(this.NumericText);
  }
    
  private void OnProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
  {    
    this.ProgressValue = e.ProgressPercentage;
    if (this.ProgressValue >= 100)
    {
      _model.PropgressChnaged -= OnProgressChanged;
    }
  }
}
```

---

A simple async command implementation that allows cancellation (based on the posted example):

```cs
public class RelayCommand : ICommand
{
  private CancellationTokenSource cancellationTokenSource;
  private readonly Func<object, Task> executeAsync;
  private readonly Func<object, CancellationToken, Task> executeCancellableAsync;
  private Action<object> execute;
  private Func<object, bool> canExecute;

  public RelayCommand(Func<object, CancellationToken, Task> executeCancellableAsync, Func<object, bool> canExecute)
  {
    this.executeCancellableAsync = executeCancellableAsync;
    this.canExecute = canExecute;
  }

  public RelayCommand(Func<object, Task> executeAsync, Func<object, bool> canExecute)
  {
    this.executeAsync = executeAsync;
    this.canExecute = canExecute;
  }

  public RelayCommand(Action<object> execute, Func<object, bool> canExecute = null)
  {
    if (execute == null)
    {
      throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(execute));
    }
      
    this.execute = execute;
    this.canExecute = canExecute;
  }

  public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged
  {
    add
    {
      CommandManager.RequerySuggested += value;
    }
    remove
    {
      CommandManager.RequerySuggested -= value;
    }
  }

  public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
  {
    return canExecute?.Invoke(parameter) ?? true;
  }

  public void Execute(object parameter)
  {
    _ = ExecuteAsync(parameter);
  }

  public async Task ExecuteAsync(object commandParameter)
  {
    using (this.cancellationTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource())
    {
      await ExecuteAsync(commandParameter, this.cancellationTokenSource.Token);
    }
  }

  public Task ExecuteAsync(object commandParameter, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
  {
    if (this.executeCancellableAsync is not null)
    {
      return this.executeCancellableAsync.Invoke(commandParameter, cancellationToken);
    }
    else if (this.executeAsync is not null)
    {
      return this.executeAsync.Invoke(commandParameter);
    }
    else
    {
      this.execute.Invoke(commandParameter);
      return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
  }

  public void Cancel()
  {
    this.cancellationTokenSource?.Cancel();
  }
}
```

Comment: BionicCode could tell also what i should change in my RelayCommand to make this class async? I have edited my post

Comment: could you also explain me this code? ```protected virtual void OnProgressCHanged(double percentage)
    => this.ProgressChanged?.Invoke(new ProgressChangedEventArgs(percentage, string.Empty); ```

Comment: I have updated the example to give you a simple async RelayCommand implementation.

Comment: The event invocator. It's a compact version using [Expression-bodied members](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/statements-expressions-operators/expression-bodied-members) and [Null-conditional operators ?.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/member-access-operators#null-conditional-operators--and-). It's the compact form of `protected virtual void OnProgressCHanged(double percentage) { if (this.ProgressChanged != null) { this.ProgressChanged.Invoke(new ProgressChangedEventArgs(percentage, string.Empty); }}`